# Flask error finding template when using flask-bootstrap

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4

I started a project and I aim to use bootstrap with flask. I am following the book FLASK WEB DEVELOPMENT (OREILLY).
I have the exact same code from the book github repository and, after importing and starting bootstrap, my templates inside the templates folder should have equals copied inside a bootstrap folder.
For example, my base.html file inside template folder would be extended, after starting bootstrap, with {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

Unfortunately, I get a template loading error, because jinja cannot find the bootstrap/base.html  file.

I initialized the virtual env, I installed flask and I pip installed flask bootstrap as well. I correctly imported flask bootstrap into hello.py and extended base.html for my user.html file.

Even so, in debug mode, I get the error that jinja cannot locate the index.html or user.html files.
I appreciate any help.

HELLO.PY FILE

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)
```

BASE.HTML FILE

```
<html>
<head>
  {% block head %}
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Application</title> 
  {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block body %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

USER.HTML FILE

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
       data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Flasky</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the hello.py file and the templates folder were NOT at the same main folder, as they should.

The templates folder was inside VENV. Big mistake, but now I know better.

Always check folder structure outside the terminal. Thank you!